# How to set default workspace location for all users?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am setting up a new VSTS source control account for use by a small team.

After reading up on the differences between Git and TFVC, I have decided to go with TFVC with *server located workspaces*.

The default in Visual Studio is local workspaces, is there a way to force all projects and users under the account to use server workspaces instead?

Comment: Server workspaces are worse than local workspaces in almost every situation. Why did you make that decision?

Comment: @DanielMann Because I read the pros and cons carefully and decided it was right for my team (being offline is never an issue).  Why do you say it is worse?  And when you say *almost*, which situation would you see it as acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to set the default workspace type is to connect to the account / collection with Visual Studio, and then go to the Team -> Team Project Collection Settings -> Source Control... option, and then the Workspace Settings tab.

[image: Menu location for Source Control Team Project Collection Settings]

Comment: Great thanks.  I thought that might be it but wasn't sure if that would affect all users regardless of their own settings.

Comment: That should set the default for all users (who create a new workspace moving forward).